# Creating A file Manager tree

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, electron

I'm making an electron app (html/css/js/nodejs) and I'm doing pretty good right now,so I wanted to create a 'Tree file manager' which is an important feature in most of the concept of my app's type. I want to be able to create delete, move, and, rename folders and content in that folders I do not want a modern file manager but at least a functional one. I have been searching for days for now and nothing. Please link resources or explain how can I achieve that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Hmmm. Maybe start by reading up and catching some tutorials. best of luck mate!

Comment: A warm welcome to StackOverflow! Have a look at here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and arrange the specific problem that you are encountering while on a code.

Comment: mm.Hello thanks for replies...well i wanted an answer not some random things,you need to understand i have searched for days and days and didnt found anything related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron comes with Node.js which has powerful file system APIs that you can use for all the functionality of your file manager.

I wrote a few functions to help you get started:

- The `getDirItemInfo()` function creates a data object for the specified path
- The `getDirItems()` function gets the contents of a directory and creates a data object for each item.

```js
const _path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

async function getDirItemInfo (path) {
  const basePath = _path.parse(path).base
  return await fetchItemObject(path, basePath)
}

async function getDirItems (dirPath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Read directory and get items
    fs.promises.readdir(dirPath)
      .then(basePaths => {
        const statsPromises = basePaths.map(basePath => {
          const path = _path.join(dirPath, basePath)
          return fetchItemObject(path, basePath)
        })
        return Promise.all(statsPromises)
      })
      .then(contents => {
        // Remove items that couldn't be accessed (undefined, null, false) 
        contents = contents
          .filter(Boolean)
        resolve(contents)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  })
}

async function fetchItemObject (path, basePath) {
  try {
    let dirItemCount = null
    const stat = await fs.promises.lstat(path)
    const name = basePath === '' ? path : basePath

    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
      // Count dir items and ignore dirs that couldn't be accessed by readdir
      try {
        const dirItems = await fs.promises.readdir(path)
        dirItemCount = dirItems.length
      }
      catch (error) { 
        console.log(error)
      }
      stat.size = null
    } 

    return ({
      dirItemCount,
      name,
      path,
      stat
    })
  } 
  catch (error) { console.log(error) }
}


// USE FUNCTIONS:
let path1 = _path.normalize('E:/test/test.jpg')
let path2 = _path.normalize('E:/test')

fetchItemObject(path1)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })

getDirItems(path2)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
```

You can find all Node.js file system APIs in their documentation:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Hello Hoffman,Thanks for all this and thanks for your time :-).
Also i understood and i will be more specific on asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Valka glad I could help. Now you can run `getDirItems('C:\\test')` to get the dir items and then render an HTML element for each of them. To make those HTML elements interactive, attach a [dblclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event) listener to each of them, and inside it add a check to see if the item is a file or a directory `item.stat.isDirectory()` (all items returned from getDirItems have `stat`). If it's a file, run Electron's `shell` module's function `shell.openPath(path)` and it will open the file, and if it's a directory run `getDirItems(path)`

Comment: im sure a lot of ppl will find this useful a lot too since direct sources online are less,Thanks a lot bless.